UseSerilogRequestLogging and additional providers
We used to do this:
 // Configure logging providers
 builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
 builder.Logging.AddSerilog();
 builder.Logging.AddCustomLoggerProvider();

However, to use UseSerilogRequestLogging you have to do services.AddSerilog()
I can't manage to get the custom logger provider to work. We tried using AddSerilog(this IServiceCollection collection, ILogger logger = null, bool dispose = false, LoggerProviderCollection providers = null) but it doesn't seem to work.
var loggerProviders = new Serilog.Extensions.Logging.LoggerProviderCollection();
loggerProviders.AddProvider(new CustomLoggerProvider());

services.AddSerilog(null, false, loggerProviders);


The builder.Services.AddSerilog() call will redirect all log events through your Serilog pipeline.

src: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/680af2e3c6b16740366d6dc4a96d20cfa9ceab01/README.md?plain=1#L51
How can we add custom logger providers to the Serilog pipeline?

The quesiton's code modifies Microsoft.Extension.Logging, not Serilog. builder.Logging.AddSerilog() configures Microsoft.Extension.Logging to use Serilog us the underlying provider. Serilog request logging works just fine, exactly as the docs show. To use it you need to configure Serilog itself, not .NET Logging.

The Serilog.AspNetCore docs clearly show that AddSerilog is used after configuring Serilog with Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().... Have you tried following the documentation?

The question is unclear - Serilog doesn't have providers, it has enrichers and sinks. builder.Logging.AddCustomLoggerProvider() doesn't affect Serilog at all, it tries to add another logging provider to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. Given how Serilog works, by replacing most of the logging middleware, this can easily break logging completely.

You can add "AddHttpLogging" to service providers.
    builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(options =>
{
    options.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.RequestHeaders |
                            HttpLoggingFields.RequestBody |
                            HttpLoggingFields.ResponseHeaders |
                            HttpLoggingFields.ResponseBody;
});

then add this to "WebApplication"
 app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
 app.UseHttpLogging();


There's no need for a custom logger. AddSerilog adds Serilog as a custom logger to Microsoft.Extensions.Serilog. Serilog itself needs to be configured separately. The question's code seems to be using Serilog.AspNetCore. The package's docs show how to configure Serilog, how to register it and how to enable request logging :
using Serilog;

//Serilog configuration
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

try
{
    Log.Information("Starting web application");

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    // Integrate Serilog with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
    builder.Services.AddSerilog(); 
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    // This enables request logging
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
 
    app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Application terminated unexpectedly");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}

The application code can keep using ILogger, but the actual logging will be performed by Serilog
Customizing logging
Services.AddSerilog effectively replaces the Microcoft.Extensions.Logging internals with Serilog, so all enrichment, filtering, export configuration needs to be done through Serilog. Luckily, Serilog supports just about everything, which is why it's one of the most popular logging libraries in .NET.
Serilog doesn't have logging providers, so asking about a "custom logging provider" doesn't explain anything. It could refer to any of the actual Serilog concepts: Sinks to export log events to various destinations, Enrichers to add extra information to log events or Filters to control what events get logged where. It could even refer to Loggers and sub-loggers
It's quite easy for example to log errors to different files or to a database, using the appropriate sinks, in this case Serilog.Sinks.File and Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer. The following code is copied as-is from an actual application, logging to the console, an error file, a log file and a database table in JSON format :
// SQL logging configuration
var columnOpts = new ColumnOptions
{
    AdditionalColumns = new Collection<SqlColumn>
    {
        new SqlColumn{ColumnName="ExecutionId",DataType=SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier},
        new SqlColumn{ColumnName="Application",DataType=SqlDbType.NVarChar,DataLength=200}
    }
};
columnOpts.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties);
columnOpts.Store.Add(StandardColumn.LogEvent);
columnOpts.LogEvent.DataLength = 2048;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
//Add some extra properties
    .Enrich.WithProperty("ExecutionId", executionId)
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", "dataloader")
// Log all to console
    .WriteTo.Console()
// Log all to a rolling daily log file
    .WriteTo.File("Logs/dataloader-log.txt", rollingInterval:RollingInterval.Day)
// Log errors only to an Errors file
    .WriteTo.File("Logs/dataloader-errors.txt",LogEventLevel.Warning, rollingInterval:RollingInterval.Day)
// Log to the database
    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
        connectionString: cns,
        sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "LogEvents",  AutoCreateSqlTable = true },
        columnOptions: columnOpts)
    .CreateLogger();

If one wanted to include eg the user or tenant to the log event, one could add this as an additional property and map it to a column.
Filtering by source, level, tenant, or anything:
In the above example a level filter is specified through the restrictedToMinimumLevel parameter. The same could be done using Filter.ByIncludingOnly :
.WriteTo.File("Logs/bsploader-errors.txt", rollingInterval:RollingInterval.Day)
    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level >= LogEventLevel.Warning)

It's also possible to filter by source. It's also possible to apply different filters and sinks by using a sublogger :
.WriteTo.Logger(c=>c.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource<CsvExporter>())
    .WriteTo.Console()
)

If the log evens are enriched eg with a user or tenant, that property can be used for filtering as well :
.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.WithProperty<string>("Tenant", 
                            p => p =="TenantWithSpecialLogging")
       .WriteTo.File("otherfile.txt",...)


yes, following the documentation works as expected, however, it is a sample for a very basic app. In my case, I have a few custom providers that log specific things. I need to somehow add these providers to the SeriLog pipeline so they are also triggered and have UseSerilogRequestLogging as well. I can make it work without UseSerilogRequestLogging 

@TylerDurden what providers are you talking about? Be specific. Serilog doesn't have providers, so the question is unclear. Microsoft.Extension.Logging does, and Serilog is one of them. Serilog has sinks like the Console, files, databases, OpenTelemetry etc. It has enrichers, that add extra information. a very basic app and nothing more is needed. I'm logging to different files with different log levels and databases and sending logs to an OpenTelemetry target (Jaeger and Aspire Dashboard) by first configuring Serilog, then telling Microsoft.Extension.Logging to use it.

custom logger providers? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider

That's not Serilog's documentation. Serilog is a "custom" logger provider, it doesn't have logger providers. You're mixing up different libraries and concepts and so it's impossible to even understand your question, much less answer it. Serilog works and supports very complex logging configurations without complex code

"That's not Serilog's documentation" ho really?... you seem confused when I talk about custom providers so I give you extra info. I'm not mixing up anything. "it doesn't have logger providers" How do you explain this extension then "AddProvider": https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/7fc50b067e9dab74e0f1ce8d5d3c7d58173fa2ef/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/Extensions/Logging/LoggerProviderCollection.cs#L23  I don't really understand your reaction. Anyway, thanks for trying.

@TylerDurden no, as I said I use Serilog already, in multiple ETL and reporting jobs, handling 2-3M transactions per month. What you linked to is the Serilog log provider for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. That's not a Serilog logging provider. You'll have a dard time finding an answer if you keep mixing up terms. You'll never find an answer if you don't explain what you actually want, no matter the terms. People that know Serilog will be able to understand what you want even with the wrong terms if you actually explain what you want, like I want to log to a database or AppInsights
